# WP7 How to get list of all available fonts

Tags: windows-phone-7, fonts

How to get list(enumeration) of all fonts in Windows phone 7. I know about list of all fonts http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff806365(v=vs.96).aspx, but is it possible to get this list programaticaly?

Comment: I need to show the list of fonts in UI to let user to select one of them from the list. I don't want to write names manualy to avoid a runtime error in the future if one or some fonts will be changed by MS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pick the available fonts from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806365%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

The WinForms had FontFamily.Families List which is not available in SL for WP7